# Why scope in Spring affects loading of class in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Class **Student** ***Depends*** on class **Result**

```
<bean id = "result" lazy-init = "false">
</bean>
<bean id = "student" lazy-init = "true">
</bean>
```

**Result:** *result* bean will be loaded at container start-up and *student* will be loaded when we call getBean method.

```
<bean id = "result" lazy-init = "false" scope = "prototype">
</bean>
<bean id = "student" lazy-init = "true" scope = "Singleton">
</bean>
```

**Result:** No bean will be loaded at container start-up.

**Question:** Why scope is affecting class load; what does scope have to do with class load time?

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made. *That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you
>   request it through a getBean() method call on the container.* As a
>   rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton
>   scope for stateless beans.

Since you didn't yet call `getBean` or inject it to another bean, this bean is not been created.

By the way, even when you declared your `singletone` bean as `lazy-init="true"`, it will be created, if you'll inject it (for example with `@Autowired` annotation) to other non-lazy bean.

Answer (score 0):

A bean of scope `singleton` is a bean that is created once per application context. A bean of scope `prototype` is a bean that is instantiated every time.

In other words if your have two classes that autowire a `singleton` scoped bean, all instances of those two classes will reference the same single instance of the bean. Doing the same with autowiring a `prototype` scoped bean will create a new instance for each instance that is autowired.

The property for `lazy-init` defines when the bean is instantiated: As a `prototype` scoped bean is instantiated each time there is no difference if the property is set to true or false, because the bean is instanciated when it is used (either by being autowired or by programmatic retrieval from the context). For a `singleton` scoped bean however it does make a difference:

- If `lazy-init` is set to `false` (which is the default), the bean is instantiated on startup.
- If the property is set to `true`, the bean is instantiated on the first use (through autowiring or programmatic retrieval from the context).

Defining a lazy load singleton bean may come in handy in cases where the bean may be costly to create and may only be used in special cases, the the application may actually run without ever calling any method on that bean.

Take a look at the [Spring IoC container documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html), which goes into great detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put the theory in a simple manner which will help you understand better,

Only Singleton beans are eager loaded | prototype beans are lazily loaded(every req or indirect references)

If singleton bean is defined as lazy-init=true (by-default its false) then bean will be instantiated on first usage(using getBean or any indirect reference)

But for prototype bean lazy-init does not make any diff if making lazy-init=true or false as it will be lazily loaded always

You can try using @PostConstruct to play around different combinations in spring bean injections to know when beans are getting instantiated.